# How to tell request.security() the source for the same crypto ticker?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to get and plot VWAP and VWAP Bands from two different platform sources.

For example you can find several ETHUSD tickers, one is Coinbase, others are Bitstamp or Bybit, Currency.com, etc.

How to specify these different platforms in `request.security()` function? To draw them on the same chart.

If this is the way. I'm afraid `request.security()` function may stall on mutable variable… Or we should tell this to the VWAP function at its `source` variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to call request.security for each ticker separately.

```
s1 = request.security("Coinbase:ETHUSD", "60", ta.vwap, ...)
s2 = request.security("Binance:ETHUSDT", "60", ta.vwap, ...)
s3 = request.security("Bybit:ETHUSDT", "60", ta.vwap, ...)
```

...